# how does 'init' /'parse_request' hook work for wordpress?

Tags: plugins, google-analytics, statistics

I wanna try to collect statistics for my wordpress website with my own plugin. the information I need is stored in $_SERVER variable. by surfing the Internet, I've two useful hooks to insert my code:

1. parse_request 2. init

Everything works fine with localhost. no data is missed, no matter it's by mobile phone or desktop, from page links or offline documents, inside apps or browser.

while it's running online, something is different. After several days collecting, i've found the collected info is not complete; sometimes i visited the website directly with mobile phone through browser or inside an app, the info will not be recorded.
but I checked the access.log, it's normal. And when running on localhost, data is saved soundly.
I cannot figure out why when put online, it will omit some data

```
function get_statistics(){
global $wpdb;
$table_name = 'table_name';
$split_str = 'separation_str';
$logdata=$_SERVER['REQUEST_TIME'].$split_str.$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'].$split_str.$_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'].$split_str.$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'].$split_str.$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'].$split_str.$_SERVER['HTTP_COOKIE'];
$logdata =substr($logdata,0,1500);

$wpdb->query( $wpdb->prepare( 'insert into '.$table_name.'(logdata) values(%s)', $logdata) );}
add_action('init','get_statistics',1);
```

Comment: Do you have a cache plugin running on your server? If you haven't installed one, does your webhost run a caching solution? If some of the requests are being served cached copies of your pages, then WordPress wouldn't necessarily be loaded, and so `init` wouldn't run.

Comment: thank you so much, it must be due to SG Optimizer which features caching solution

Comment: As a solution, you could use JS, so after the page has been loaded you then uses AJAX to trigger your PHP and that would insert your data regardless of whether or not the page was being cached.  This could also allow the page to be loaded without the PHP running which would improve your user's experience.  The process of saving the data isn't needed for the user, it's needed by you, so triggering it after the page is loaded is actually beneficial.